# Objective-C - how can separately parse attributes of my XML?

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing

I'm working on an application where I use XML parsing in `UITableView`. I can not figure out how I'm separately parses attributes `rok1` and `rok2`. If I use `[_element isEqualToString: @ "jmeno"]` application works well, but it displayed to me in `UITableView` together `rok1` and `rok2` and do not want it. Thx for your help.

There is my parser code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    self.element = elementName;

    if ([_element isEqualToString:@"rok1"])
    {
        _item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        self.nazev   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.definice    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{ 
    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"nazev"])
    {
        [self.nazev appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"def"])
    {
        [self.definice appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rok1"])
        {
        Slova *thisSvatek = [[Slova alloc] initWithName:self.nazev
                                              definice:self.definice];
        [self.svatkyArray addObject:thisSvatek];
    }
    self.element = nil;
}
```

And example of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu>
    <rok1>
        <jmeno>
        <nazev>Prvni</nazev>
        <def>blblbla</def>
        <jmeno>
        <nazev>Druhy</nazev>
        <def>blbablabal</def>
        </jmeno>
   </rok1>
   <rok2>
        <jmeno>
        <nazev>Prvni</nazev>
        <def>blblbla</def>
        </jmeno>
   </rok2>
</menu>
```

Comment: How do you want to display the data? In two sections? Ignore rok2?

Comment: My idea is that I would like to display (for example after the click on UIButton) data only from rok1 or only from rok2. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of your "state" as you are parsing the XML document.  One simple approach is simply to add a boolean property that indicates that you are processing 'inside' the target element.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    self.element = elementName;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rok1"])
    {
        self.foundTarget=YES;
        self.nazev   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.definice    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{ 
    if (self.foundTarget) {
        if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"nazev"])
        {
            [self.nazev appendString:string];
        }
        else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"def"])
        {
            [self.definice appendString:string];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rok1"])
    {
        Slova *thisSvatek = [[Slova alloc] initWithName:self.nazev
                                              definice:self.definice];
        [self.svatkyArray addObject:thisSvatek];
        self.foundTarget=NO;
    }
    self.element = nil;
}
```

A more sophisticated approach is to build some sort of data structure, such as a dictionary, that represents your XML

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    self.element = elementName;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rok1"]  || [elementName.isEqualToString:@"rok2"])
    {
        self.nazev   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.definice    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{ 
        if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"nazev"])
        {
            [self.nazev appendString:string];
        }
        else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"def"])
        {
            [self.definice appendString:string];
        }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rok1"]  || [elementName.isEqualToString:@"rok2"])
        Slova *thisSvatek = [[Slova alloc] initWithName:self.nazev
                                              definice:self.definice];
        self.rokDictionary[elementName]=thisSvatek; // self.rokDictionary is an NSMutableDictionary
    }
    self.element = nil;
}
```

To separate out the various 'jmeno' tags, you need to handle them in `didStartElement` & `didEndElement` -

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    self.element = elementName;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rok1"]  || [elementName.isEqualToString:@"rok2"])
    {
        self.jmenoArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"jmeno"]) {
        self.nazev   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.definice    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{ 
        if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"nazev"])
        {
            [self.nazev appendString:string];
        }
        else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"def"])
        {
            [self.definice appendString:string];
        }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"jmeno"]) {
        Slova *thisSvatek = [[Slova alloc] initWithName:self.nazev
                                              definice:self.definice];
        [self.jemnoArray addObject:thisSvatek];
    } 
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rok1"]  || [elementName.isEqualToString:@"rok2"])

        self.rokDictionary[elementName]=self.jmenoArray; // self.rokDictionary is an NSMutableDictionary
        self.jmenoArray=nil;
    }
    self.element = nil;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice, but if you use your code, entire contents (from rok1) is displayed to one Cell in UITableView. Probably because it is ignored attribute <jmeno>

Comment: Yes, because that is what your original code did.  If you want something different then you need to handle it in didStartElement/didEndElement.  Probably allocat a new NSMutableArray in `didStartElement` for <jmeno> and add the string to the array in `didEndElement` for <jmeno> and add the array to the dictionary in `didEndElement` for <rok>

Comment: Ok, but this is actually my biggest problem that I can not solve (sorry but I'm still a newbie) :-)